# Understanding Red-Black Tree Traversal of STL multiset in GDB

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, red-black-tree

I am trying to understand the RB-tree traversal in the following [GDB script](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt)

```
define pset
    if $argc == 0
        help pset
    else
        set $tree = $arg0
        set $i = 0
        set $node = $tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_left
        set $end = $tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header
        set $tree_size = $tree._M_t._M_impl._M_node_count
        if $argc == 1
            printf "Set "
            whatis $tree
            printf "Use pset <variable_name> <element_type> to see the elements in the set.\n"
        end
        if $argc == 2
            while $i < $tree_size
                set $value = (void *)($node + 1)
                printf "elem[%u]: ", $i
                p *($arg1*)$value
                if $node._M_right != 0
                    set $node = $node._M_right
                    while $node._M_left != 0
                        set $node = $node._M_left
                    end
                else
                    set $tmp_node = $node._M_parent
                    while $node == $tmp_node._M_right
                        set $node = $tmp_node
                        set $tmp_node = $tmp_node._M_parent
                    end
                    if $node._M_right != $tmp_node
                        set $node = $tmp_node
                    end
                end
                set $i++
            end
        end
```

I went through [stl_tree.h](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_tree.h) to understand the internals of the RB-tree but could't get it. These are my following doubts-

1. Is it iterative in-order traversal thats happening here?
2. How can `$end = $tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header`. I thought `_M_header` is the root node. If not which is the root node?
3. If its inorder traversal then why are we first going down the right sub-tree of the tree by doing `if $node._M_right != 0 set $node = $node._M_right`. Also, we are printing out the element right at the beginning of the while loop as we do in pre-order. But when I run this script in GDB, it does print the elements in sorted order which makes me speculate that its in-order.
4. When it comes to traversal, isn't an RB-tree the same as a normal BST? Cant an RB-tree traversed with just left and right pointers? Why is parent pointer being used here?

Comment: It's worth noting that these gdb scripts have been obsoleted by the Python pretty-printers that are shipped with libstdc++.  Those work directly with `print` and in ordinary setups don't require any special configuration.

Comment: @TomTromey Sadly, a lot of (multiarch-enabled) stable releases of Debian/Ubuntu ship with broken libstdc++ debug packages ... still, it's worth hunting down the fixes.

Comment: On Fedora at least the damage was historically limited to bad glib (since fixed) and mono (no clue) debug helpers.  But we at least managed to get libstdc++ right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

All my above questions can be answered with one observation-
"`tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header` is NOT the root node. It is a node that acts like a cache for the RB-tree. That is `tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_Left` points to the leftmost node of the tree, `tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_Right` points to the rightmost node and `tree._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_parent` points to the root node of the tree.

Now, we can see how the given code is indeed doing an in-order traversal. The reason as to why normal BST traversal is not used here is to gain speed. By caching the leftmost node of the tree, things like `iterator.begin()` can be implemented in `O(1)` instead of `O(h)` where `h` is the height of the tree.

Comment: Better just call it `O(log(n))`. Anyway, the key to recognizing an iterative in-order traversal are the while loops preceded by `set $node = $node._M_right
` (has right child, next is leftmost node of right child) and `set $tmp_node = $node._M_parent` (no right child, go up until there is one). I would not even look at the initialization/termination logic, which is somewhat unusual here. Anyway, you really should be using the new pretty-printer stuff instead of custom per-class commands.